# Align an inline div right within a text paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div containing text of variable lengths

```
<div id="paragraph">
   blah blah blah <em>Something Important</em> more blah
</div>
```

I want to dynamically append another `<div id="buttons">` that contains two buttons to the above, and this `<div id="buttons">` should always align right and appear inline within the containing `<div id="paragraph">`. For example, it could look like

```
This is a paragraph, and part of it are two buttons that should always align right at the end.                  [button1][button2]
```

How do I do the appending `<div id="buttons">` part in JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it that way, HTML:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit atque quae officiis deserunt ea quis dolorum laudantium repudiandae suscipit eligendi consequatur amet optio fugit doloribus qui beatae officia laborum cumque!
    <a href="" class="btn">Button 1</a>
    <a href="" class="btn">Button 2</a>
</p>
```

and CSS:

```
p {
    text-align: left;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #b30;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: User is asking to dynamically append a div, this isn't dynamic

Comment: @sunpietro, thanks for the suggestion. But can I use `float` together with `inline-block`?

Comment: in that situation, I think yes, but the theory suggests that after using float it should behave like display: block

Answer (score 0):

In html add a container for both your first div and your appended div (I also added a link to append the button):

```
<a href="#" id='appender' onclick="appendBtn()">append</a>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='paragraph'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,tofficia laborum cumqu
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS should be very similar to what the previous answer said:

```
#paragraph {
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
}
.newDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 5px;
  float: right;
}
.btn {
  background: #b30;
  color: #fff;}
```

and the jQuery needed to append:

```
function appendBtn(){
  var myDivs =  '<div class="newDiv"><a href="#" class="btn">Button1</a></div>';
  $('#container').append(myDivs);
}
```

EDIT: I forgot, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bpdkx/27/